# Difference between "select t from table t" and "from table" in HQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am new to hibernate, But in some cases I have seen that we are writing query as

```
(select t from table t)
```

and in some cases we are writing query as

```
(from table t) i.e without select
```

Is there any difference between above two queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular example, if instead of table you'd use an actual Entity than there would be no difference.

The second form is the short version of the first as long as you use HQL.

This doesn't apply to the SQL standard, so it's just a [Hibernate Query Language specific syntax](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-from).

Comment: Missing a big difference, one is JPA standard and the other isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is technically correct but omits the most important difference.
"FROM blah" IS NOT PORTABLE. It is not JPA, and is only usable in Hibernate. Use that and your code will not be usable in other JPA implementations.

Comment: Good point and it's much more expressive. The short-cut version doesn't buy you that much to bother using it.